# Flat JSON array into structured form in JAVA

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some problem with converting flat structure of JSON, into structured form.
We receive data from service in this form:

```
[
 {'key':"Main1.del[1].x", "value": 0 },
 {'key':"Main1.del[1].y", "value": 1 },
 {'key':"Main1.del[2].x", "value": 5 },
 {'key':"Main1.del[2].y", "value": 7 },
 {'key':"Custom.stat[1].rev.max", "value": 45 },
 {'key':"Custom.stat[1].rev.min", "value": -65 }
]
```

But we need to transform that into this form:

```
{
 "Main1":{
   "del":[
     {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 1
     },
     {
      "x": 5,
      "y": 7
     }
   ]
 },
 "Custom":{
  "stat":[
   {
    "rev":{
      "max":45,
      "min":-65,
     }
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Is there some solution for this transformation in Java? Actually we are using Jackson for serializing and deserializing JSON data.

I am sorry if is there same topic, I have not found it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any library doing that for you, you have to write code for that yourself:

You have to parse the key values into their elements, and for these elements, you have to create the necessary structures on demand, e.g. `"Main1.del[1].x"` means you need

- a top-level object node (create that if it isn't already there),
- a `Main1` field in that object (create that if it isn't already there),
- a `.` operator meaning that `Main1` is an object node (create that if it isn't already there),
- a `del` field in `Main1` (create that if it isn't already there),
- a `[1]` indexing, meaning that `del` is an array node with at least one or two elements (depending on zero- or one-based array indexing - create that if it isn't already there - extend it if it is too short),
- a `.` operator meaning that the array element is an object node (create that if it isn't already there),
- an `x` field in the array element object (create that if it isn't already there).

Finally, assign the `value` to that last node.

For creating your structured JSON objects, you can also use Jackson with classes like `ObjectNode`, `ArrayNode` and so on. But you might as well want to create this as POJO on the fly without introducing another intermediate JSON layer.